# Tcpreplay in Android?

Tags: android, pcap, libpcap

I am performing some experiments where **I want to replay a previously captured packet trace from Android**. So far I have written my own application to replay the trace and get then answer back from the server. Timing accuracy is not a big problem as long as is within reasonable bounds (e.g., some milliseconds).

However, I would prefer to use a tested tool like tcpreplay. **Is there any project that have ported tcpreplay to Android?** Given that libpcap is available, there should be something available, but I could not find anything.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of tcpreplay, and I can't say I'm aware of an Android port.  Never owned an Android device so can't say one is coming anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So far my application covers my needs, but if I see the need of porting it to Android I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it running on my tab, you need to install GNUroot and Debian no root, they are both from the same developer... After get it, open GNUroot, check emulate new root, create rootfs and run the rootfs, after this "apt-get install tcpreplay". If you want to capture use TpacketCapture in the play store, you can also get Tpacketcapture Pro to use the capture in only one app.
If you are planning to hack games don't publish it, cause this vulnerability can be easily patched...
any question email me.